# The attribute 'debug' has been locked in a higher level configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

Im trying to upload a MVC site to a server but it just seems it wont play ball. Never had such weird errors for uploading a mvc site. 
Get this message when I navigate to the web page.

```
The attribute 'debug' has been locked in a higher level configuration.
```

What the h... does that mean?

Source error:

```
An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
```

some part of the web.config that I have been messing around with:

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
<compilation debug="false" />
```

Comment: try accessing the your web app from your server browser, you could see the error details in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the `debug` attribute has been set at machine level and you are not allowed to change it. This is done in the global IIS configuration file that you won't have access to. In effect, a `web.config` just inherits from that and all your XML is just overriding or adding to those values.

Now I assume it's been locked to prevent `debug="true"`, this means you can just remove that attribute completely, which means you can remove the entire `compilation` element.

Comment: Ok that helped a bit more. Now I get to the actual error. Thanks